# Failed to load AppCompat ActionBar with unknown error. sdk 28 seems to be cause

Tags: android, xml, sdk, android-gradle-plugin

This is my gradle file where I make the changes but anything I do with SDK 28 doesn't help me but when I change it to 27. It works. Please help me to make it work with SDK 28. Thank you.
//This is my app gradle(Module:base)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.feature'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28 //Change is made here
    baseFeature true
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 28 //Change is made here
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    api 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-beta01'//Change is made here
    api 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
    application project(':app')
    feature project(':project')
}

//If I change the SDK version to 27, it works. I really want to find out how to make it work in SDK version 28

//Thank you for helping
```

Comment: What mean `application` and `feature`?

Answer (score 0):

Click Tools > SDK Manager.

In the SDK Platforms tab, select Android P Preview.

In the SDK Tools tab, select Android SDK Build-Tools 28-rc2 (or higher).

Click OK to begin install.

Make sure you have Android Studio 3.1 or higher.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I am afraid, I tried it and it didn't work. Anything else you could suggest that I could do. Thank you